# Enable network tracing in dotnet core console application

Tags: .net-core

I am writing a dotnet core console application that uses the HttpClient to make an HTTPS request that requires a client certificate.   In .Net I can enable system diagnostics in the app.config (or web.config) and it will output lots of information about the SSL connection.  Is there a similar functionality in dotnet core?

In .Net I would add this to the app.config:

```
 <system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true"/>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.Net" maxdatasize="1024">
      <listeners>
        <add name="TraceFile"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.Net.Sockets" maxdatasize="1024">
      <listeners>
        <add name="TraceFile"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="TraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
      initializeData="trace.log"/>
  </sharedListeners>
  <switches>
    <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
    <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose" />
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29210

Comment: @LexLi - I'm running on MacOS and that appears to be Windows

Comment: [dotnet-trace](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/master/documentation/dotnet-trace-instructions.md)